# How to convert between time units in .NET?

Tags: .net, datetime, time, integer

What `.NET` functions allow conversion between time units?

eg: If I have an `Integer` which I know represents a time duration in minutes, what is the best way in `.NET` to convert that number to milliseconds?

```
Dim durationInMinutes as Integer = 10
Dim durationInMilliseconds As Integer = <???>(10);  // what is the function to use here?
```

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm sure you mean `minutes * 60 * 1000` and you were just testing people, right? ;)

Comment: Yep!! I have to get entertainment somehow!  ....... ;)

Comment: @MitchWheat: doesn't that prove the point that an in-built function is better to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int minutes = 5;
int milliseconds = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: The TotalMilliseconds property actually returns a double - don't forget to cast it!